# how to solve Unexpected return value in RxJava onSuccess() method?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I was going to refactor one of my method from this:

```
if (!isMobileBluetoothOn()) {
            sendError();
            return false;
        }
```

to this

```
getBluetoothState().subscribe(state->{
            if(!state.isEnabled()){
                sendError();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

but I am getting this error in the IDE `"UnExpected return value"`, How can I return the boolean value in the onSuccess method?

Comment: use `map` instead of `subscribe ` and you'll get `Observable<Boolean>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd suggest you to split logic here to something like:

```
Observable<Boolean> isBluetoothEnabled = getBluetoothState()
    .map(state -> {state.isEnabled()})
    .replay(1)
    .refCount()
...
// use isBluetoothEnabled for something you need
...
isBluetoothEnabled
    .subscribe(isEnabled -> {
        if (!isEnabled) {
            sendError()
        }
    })
```

Comment: Actually I am calling this inside a method which's return type is boolean and I want to return that boolean from onSubscribed method

Comment: @Reyjohn this is not possible `subscribe()` operator returns only `Subscription` object (which you need to unsubscribe somewhere, btw). As i mentioned in answer: you can use `isBluetoothEnabled.map {...}` to get this boolean

Answer (score 0):

I really do not know your situation but you say :

> Actually I am calling this inside a method which's return type is boolean and I
>   want to return that boolean from onSubscribed method

It looks like you going to get boolean value synchronously. It is absolutely bad practice for reactive programming but anyway you can use you `Observable` as `BlockingObservable`. Code looks like this :

```
val isEnabled = getBluetoothState().toBlocking().first().isEnabled()
```

You can read more about `BlockingObservable` here: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/BlockingObservable.html

Try to avoid this practice but sometimes you must use it and may be it is your case.

Good luck!